# Static Variables and Thread-Local Storage

Tags: c++, multithreading, static

**Background:**

I have discovered something of an interesting edge case relating to static memory initialization across multiple threads.  Specifically, I am using Howard Hinnant's TZ library which has been working fine for the rest of my code across many different threads.

Now, I am developing a logging class which relies on yet another thread and condition variable.  Unfortunately, when I attempt to format a chrono `time_point` using `date::make_zoned(data::locate_zone("UTC"), tp)` the library crashes.  Upon digging through `tz.cpp`, I find that the time zone database returned internally is evaluating to `NULL`.  This all comes from the following snippet:

```
tzdb_list&
get_tzdb_list()
{
    static tzdb_list tz_db = create_tzdb();
    return tz_db;
}
```

As can be seen, the database list is stored statically.  With a few printf()s and some time with GDB I can see that the same db is returned for multiple calls from the main thread but returns `NULL` when called from my logger thread.

If, however, I change the declaration of `tzdb_list` to:

```
static thread_local tzdb_list tz_db = create_tzdb();
```

Everything works as expected.  This is not surprising as `thread_local` will cause each thread to do the heavy-lifting of creating a standalone instance of `tzdb_list`.  Obviously this is wasteful of memory and can easily cause problems later.  As such, I really don't see this as a viable solution.

**Questions:**

- **What about the invocation of one thread versus another would cause static memory to behave differently?**  If anything, I would expect the opposite of what is happening (eg. for the threads to 'fight' over initialized memory; not have one receive a `NULL` pointer).
- **How is it possible for a returned static reference to have multiple different values in the first place (in my case, valid memory versus `NULL`)?**
- **With `thread_local` built into the library I get wildly different memory locations on opposite ends of the addressable region; why?**  I suspect that this has to do with where thread memory is allocated versus the main process memory but do not know the exact details of thread allocation regions.

**Reference:**

My logging thread is created with:

```
outputThread = std::thread(Logger::outputHandler, &outputQueue);
```

And the actual output handler / invocation of the library (`LogMessage` is just a typedef for `std::tuple`):

```
void Logger::outputHandler(LogQueue *queue)
{
    LogMessage entry;
    std::stringstream ss;

    while (1)
    {
        queue->pop(entry);           // Blocks on a condition variable

        ss << date::make_zoned(date::locate_zone("UTC"), std::get<0>(entry))
           << ":" << levelId[std::get<1>(entry)
           << ":" << std::get<3>(entry) << std::endl;

        // Printing stuff

        ss.str("");
        ss.clear();
    }
}
```

Additional code and output samples available on request.

---

**EDIT 1**

This is definitely a problem in my code.  When I strip *everything* out my logger works as expected.  What is strange to me is that my test case in the full application is just two prints in main and a call to the logger before manually exiting.  None of the rest of the app initialization is run but I am linking in all support libraries at that point (Microsoft CPP REST SDK, MySQL Connector for C++ and Howard's date library (static)).

It is easy for me to see how something could be stomping this memory but, even in the "full" case in my application, I don't know why the prints on the main thread would work but the next line calling into the logger would fail.  If something were going sideways at init I would expect all calls to break.

I also noticed that if I make my logger static the problem goes away.  Of course, this changes the memory layout so it doesn't rule out heap / stack smashing.  What I do find interesting is that I can declare the logger globally or on the stack at the start of `main()` and both will segfault in the same way.  If I declare the logger as static, however, both global and stack-based declaration work.

Still trying to create a minimal test case which reproduces this.

I am already linking with `-lpthread`; have been pretty much since the inception of this application.

OS is Fedora 27 x86_64 running on an Intel Xeon.  Compiler:

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 7.3.1 20180130 (Red Hat 7.3.1-2)
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: One question per question please

Comment: show asm code of `get_tzdb_list()` and trace `get_tzdb_list()` call from logger thread for view what happens

Comment: IMHO ,the fact that NULL is returned (which shouldn't be possible) is a sign that your program has at least 1 serious BUG.

Comment: "Additional code and output samples available on request" -- see the instructions in stackoverflow.com's [help] for creating a [mcve], that anyone can compile themselves in order to reproduce the problem you're observing. Without a [mcve], it's unlikely that anyone will be able to tell you anything.

Comment: @engf-010: I do not doubt the problem is with my code; I just don't know how.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik:  Working on a minimal example but it is taking a lot of time to isolate this particular functionality.  This code is buried in the belly of a decently-sized code base.

Comment: Need a [MCVE], all in one piece.

Comment: It's very likely that your effort to provide a [mcve] will result in you isolating the underlying bug in the code. In any case, without a minimal, complete example there's nothing that can be said about this.

Comment: The C++ standard says that a function local static initialization is thread safe:  One thread will initialize it, and all other threads will wait until the initialization is complete.  Shot in the dark:  compile with `-lpthread`, though I would have thought that not having this would've caused a link-time error instead of a run-time error.

Comment: Which compiler & version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Are you using a version of tz.cpp that includes this commit from Jan 5: https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/commit/55289f0d73b51b21ed02ec27114384ebd7b94d6c ?  This commit fixed an initialization order problem that can occur.

Comment: @HowardHinnant: That seemed to fix it (was using a version from Nov of last year).  No idea why this particular thread would be affected while the others were just fine.  Regardless, please post this in an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that this problem was caused by a [bug in tz.cpp which has since been fixed](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/commit/55289f0d73b51b21ed02ec27114384ebd7b94d6c).

The bug was that there was a namespace scope variable whose initialization was not guaranteed in the proper order.  This was fixed by turning that variable into a function-local-static to ensure the proper initialization order.

My apologies to all who might have been impacted by this bug.  And my thanks to all those who have reported it.